# Match open and closing brackets that don't have atleast two semicolons

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text like this:

> [Unix; common] To expand special characters in a wildcarded name, or
>   the act of so doing (the action is also called [[b;#fff;]globbing]).
>   The Unix conventions for filename wildcarding have become sufficiently
>   pervasive that many hackers use some of them in written English,
>   especially in email or news on technical topics. Those commonly
>   encountered include the following:Some examples: [[i;;]He said his
>   name was [KC]arl] (expresses ambiguity). [[i;;]I don't read
>   talk.politics.*] (any of the talk.politics subgroups on
>   [[bu;#fff;;jargon]Usenet]). Other examples are given under the entry
>   for [[bu;#fff;;jargon]X]. Note that glob patterns are similar, but not
>   identical, to those used in [[bu;#fff;;jargon]regexp]s.Historical
>   note: The jargon usage derives from glob, the name of a subprogram
>   that expanded wildcards in archaic pre-Bourne versions of the Unix
>   shell.

and I want to replace `[KC]` and `[Unix; common]` by `\[KC\]` and `\[Unix; common\]`

I've try this regex:

```
/\[(?![^;]*;[^;]*;[^\]]*\])[^\]]+\]/g
```

but it don't work.

Comment: But only one, updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small change. You also need to include `\]` along with `;` inside the negated char class because `[^;]` should also match `]`, so it should exceed the closing bracket `]`.

```
\[((?![^;\]]*;[^;\]]*;[^\]]*\])[^\]]+)\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nQ3jI8/2)